# javascript google maps api - disable zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to disable zooming after calling fitbounds (which determines the right zoom level). I tried setting min and max zoom values but it does not work.
Here is my code:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        //south, west
        new google.maps.LatLng(minLat, minLon), 
        //north, east
        new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, maxLon)
);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
currentZoom = map.getZoom();
map.setOptions({maxZoom: currentZoom, minZoom: currentZoom});
```

Just to make it clear, what I want to disable is mouse zooming.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.fitBounds` is asynchronous, you need to add an event listener for the `zoom_changed` event.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    map.setOptions({
        maxZoom: currentZoom,
        minZoom: currentZoom
    });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z21vx4e8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
//  Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
//  Baltimore, MD, USA (39.2903848, -76.6121893)
var maxLat = 40.735657;
var maxLon = -74.1723667;
var minLat = 39.2903848;
var minLon = -76.6121893;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    //south, west
    new google.maps.LatLng(minLat, minLon),
    //north, east
    new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, maxLon));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    map.setOptions({
      maxZoom: currentZoom,
      minZoom: currentZoom
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).

Disable scroll wheel, button, and double click zooming:

```
map.setOptions({zoomControl: false, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});
```

Comment: it did not work. Scrollwheel was not on the map already. I want to disable mouse zooming

Comment: Check for errors in browser console. The above should disable all types of zooming with the mouse. The `zoomControl: false` should disable the +/- buttons on the UI.

Comment: This not what I was looking for geocodezip gave the right answer. thank you for help anyway.